# Why import builtins if you never redefine any built-in functions?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-import

I am looking at the code in this repo https://github.com/datacenter/cobra and I am seeing imports from builtins as follows in a few files:

```
cobra/internal/codec/jsoncodec.py:15:from builtins import str
cobra/internal/codec/xmlcodec.py:15:from builtins import str
cobra/internal/base/moimpl.py:16:from builtins import next
cobra/internal/base/moimpl.py:17:from builtins import str
cobra/internal/base/moimpl.py:18:from builtins import object
cobra/internal/rest/accessimpl.py:15:from builtins import object
cobra/internal/rest/accessimpl.py:16:from builtins import str
cobra/mit/session.py:15:from builtins import str
cobra/mit/session.py:16:from builtins import object
cobra/mit/meta.py:16:from builtins import str
cobra/mit/meta.py:17:from builtins import next
cobra/mit/meta.py:18:from builtins import object
cobra/mit/access.py:21:from builtins import object
cobra/mit/naming.py:15:from builtins import next
cobra/mit/naming.py:16:from builtins import str
cobra/mit/naming.py:17:from builtins import object
cobra/mit/request.py:15:from builtins import str
cobra/mit/request.py:16:from builtins import object
```

What is the logic/what is gained by doing this? There is no place in the module where these objects are re-defined.

On a side note, this breaks the 2.7 compatibility I was expecting from this module as specified in the docs.

Comment: Maybe a good better idea should be to ask to project's developers why the hell they do this!

Comment: Having those names in the module namespace will 1. be very slightly more performant than accessing them in as built-ins, and 2. not be affected by any later-imported modules' redefinitions of built-ins. Why they did it, I can't say; people just liked it better that way...

Comment: Which case you need performance importing builtins methods? And, this approach does not works on Python 2.x

Comment: @MauroBaraldi - On 2.x, `builtins` comes from `pip install futures`. There isn't a native `builtins` module.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know why its done in cobra specifically, but its a trick for writing code that works in python 2 and 3. See [compatible_idioms](http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html#basestring). It shouldn't break 2.7 but you have to write "3x-ish" code.

*update*

For 2.x, the `builtins` module needs to be installed from `pypi`. Its not the native builtin functions, but 3.x compatible updates.

Comment: Note `builtins` is part of the _future_ pypi package (i.e. it can be installed via `pip install future`)