# Does from builtins import * have any affect

Tags: python, python-3.x

Does `from builtins import *` actually do anything? Isn't everything from builtins already imported on every script?

Comment: from the docs: *"This module is not normally accessed explicitly by most applications, but can be useful in modules that provide objects with the same name as a built-in value, but in which the built-in of that name is also needed. "*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why import builtins if you never redefine any built-in functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29306516/why-import-builtins-if-you-never-redefine-any-built-in-functions)

Comment: If you do it in Python 2.x, I think all the builtin functions will then behave like Python 3.x.